# C# upload a file to conversion service then download resulting file to specific folder

Tags: c#, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I've inherited a C# script which is supposed to upload a pdf file to a [converter service](https://pdftables.com/pdf-to-excel-api) and then download the resulting converted file.  But it seems the download part is missing from this script.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using CustomScript.Api;

public class Script
{
    public static CustomScriptReturn CustomScript(CustomScriptArguments args)
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
              httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "token");
              MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();  
              byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\user1\Documents\Test\Files\test1.pdf");
              form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length), "test1", "test1.pdf"); 
              HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://pdftables.com/api?key=1234567&format=html", form).Result; 
            }
        return CustomScriptReturn.Empty();
    }
}
```

This script runs without error in the program we're using but nothing actually  gets downloaded, despite the fact that the support staff for the converter service indicated this as being correct.  Perhaps the issue is with the `return CustomScriptReturn.Empty` line, but I'm not sure as I'm relatively new to `C#`.

What code would need to be added to this to download the converted file to the same filepath that the input file is in?

Comment: It should be part of the response variable

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: change HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://pdftables.com/api?key=1234567&format=html", form).Result;  to HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://pdftables.com/api?key=1234567&format=html", form); and then on the following line do a var content = response.Content; and set a breakpoint on that. You can inspect the response.Content which should contain the return data you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

When you do a POST to a web service, in this case on that will convert a pdf to a chosen format, the conversion will happen and it will spit the converted data back at you. This is part of the Content of the return data. Your current code is set to always return

```
return CustomScriptReturn.Empty();
```

which is part of the reason that you will never see any of the data you seek. A better method would be to get the full response

```
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://pdftables.com/api?key=1234567&format=html", form)
```

and then you can check to ensure everything is good before sending back a CustomScriptReturn.Empty() such as ensuring that the HTTP request status is OK sending the converted content stream or if it is not send Empty

```
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://pdftables.com/api?key=1234567&format=html", form)
if ((int)response.StatusCode == 200)
{
    //obviously you will need to handle converting the return data to your custom type
    return (CustomScriptReturn)response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
else
{
    return CustomScriptReturn.Empty();
}
```